# How to get results in elastic search in an order with respect to first findings from a given input string?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nlp

I am new to elastic search and trying to query a string.

Below is my query:

```
GET observations_corpus/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "OBSERVATION.keyword": {
              "query": "RDW-CV=16.8%, WBC=9.010*3, RBC=3.2210*6",
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
              "operator": "or",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 6.111533,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "observations_corpus",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0",
        "_score" : 6.111533,
        "_source" : {
          "OBSERVATION" : "WBC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "observations_corpus",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 6.111533,
        "_source" : {
          "OBSERVATION" : "RBC"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "observations_corpus",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : 4.9527483,
        "_source" : {
          "OBSERVATION" : "RDW-CV"
        }
      }
```

}

In my Query, the order of required tokens is "RDW-CV, WBC, RBC" but in output hits, the order changed like "WBC, RBC, RDW-CV".

Is there any way that we can get the hits w.r.t input order?
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'll say is that there's no feature in Elasticsearch AFAIK that will sort your results the way you want. I'll outline something that I feel is a hack below, but I feel the most "proper" solution would be to run separate queries for each of your search terms and compose the Elasticsearch results in your client application. So in your example, break your query up into three queries. Elasticsearch is a distributed search engine, depending on your setup you may have different servers that can process each constituent query, and submitting these multiple queries in parallel could still give you good response times.

That being said, as an alternative here is a hack that might work for you. The hack is basically using a boolean query with each token in its own clause, and using different boosts to prefer matches on the first token over the second, and the second token over the third. This isn't guaranteed to always give you the ordering you want, but you can play with the boosts and set them to something that *should* always work for you:

```
GET observations_corpus/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "OBSERVATION.keyword": {
              "query": "RDW-CV=16.8%",
              "boost": 100
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
              "operator": "or",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "OBSERVATION.keyword": {
              "query": "WBC=9.010*3",
              "boost": 10
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
              "operator": "or",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "OBSERVATION.keyword": {
              "query": "RBC=3.2210*6",
              "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
              "operator": "or",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        },
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }  
  }
}
```